# Webkit Box Reflect z-index not behaving correctly

Tags: html, css, webkit, z-index

The `-webkit-box-reflect` styling property does not seem to respect the z-index of its selector. Did I do something wrong or is it meant to be like that?

my `#main_menu` element has a `z-index` value of **1** while the elements beneath it have `z-index` values of **4** for the `#action_menu` and the `#content`. I also tried setting the z-index of the section itself higher and it didn't change anything.

**Tldr**; The reflection is shown above other elements with higher z-index. Why so?

Code below:

**http://jsfiddle.net/uLrkq/**

Comment: it'll be easier to look at if you kept your code compacts

Comment: @SanderH Just for you then: http://jsfiddle.net/uLrkq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your section has `position: static;`, give it `position: relative;` (for instance) and a `z-index` of 4.

Comment: Thank you, your answer didn't need anything else and you went straight to the point. That's all that I wanted. That's also a fact I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property only works on positioned elements, or those that have an `opacity` value less than 1. These create what is known as a new stacking context.

In every case where you use `z-index` in your example, you neither position the element nor set its opacity. The best way to fix it would be to add `position: relative` to each declaration block that you use `z-index`. If you use `relative` positioning without specifying an offset, it will remain in the same position as it is now, but respect the `z-index`.